# Combining two arrays to create a two dimensional array in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
```

How would I combine the two arrays in a 2D array?:

```
[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try [Array#zip](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-zip)

```
a.zip(b)
=> [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]
```

Comment: Tx. Kulbir! Didn't know that existed.

Answer (score 10):

While `zip` is obviously the most straightforward answer, this also works:

```
[a, b].transpose
=> [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```